# How to copy file to System32 with batch

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have this code:

```
@echo off
:CheckOS
IF "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%"=="x86" (set bit=x86) else (set bit=x64)
echo THIS COMPUTER'S ARCHITECTURE IS %bit%
IF "%bit%"=="x86" (
    xcopy /s /h "%~dp0%var.exe" "%windir%\system32\"
)
IF "%bit%"=="x64" (
    xcopy /s /h "%~dp0%var64.exe" "%windir%\system32\"
)
PAUSE
```

And I get the error `Invalid path`.

I also tried without the `%~dp0%` or using the `C:\Windows\System32` and I get the same error

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: system32 is a system folder. Are you running your script with administrative rights?

Comment: @LPChip Yes, if i don't i get the Access Denied error

Comment: Is the file located in the source file on a network path that is mapped to a network drive, and as such, when running as Administrator, that drivemapping is gone?

Comment: the var.exe and var64.exe are in the same folder as the batch file. Actually, not the same folder, but the same removable drive

Comment: @root from the root directory of a removable drive

Comment: Are you sure your variables are what you think they are?
Use the SET command in the command prompt to verify the variable values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`XCOPY`](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true) the switches go after the source and destination paths. That would explain the path error.

**Syntax:** XCOPY *source [destination] [/switches]*

Try `xcopy "%~dp0%var64.exe" "%windir%\system32\"  /s /h`.

Comment: Figured out what was the problem: Since i was running the batch file from a removable drive, i had to enter the "F:" command [F being the drive letter] in order to move my operations into that drive. Now it works fine